# Amplify GraphQL No Credentials Error in NextJs Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

NextJs Application is working perfectly fine locally but after pushing the fronted to AWS I'm getting the run time error,  **No Credentials** in ***callback.js*** api

No Build time error, so I assume aws-exports.js file is built correctly during the build but I don't know if it is built with the required details like API key on AWS.

I'm using API key authentication by default. I'm not using amplify add auth because I've a requirement to use custom auth. I know amplify auth is the recommend way but I still need to use my custom method.

I have already tried multiple suggestions like disable Analytics: true  as suggested in couple of other discussions but none of them worked for me. Build my project multiple times from scratch by re-installing all the dependencies but no luck.

**callback.js API**

```js
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import {getAuth} from "../../../../src/graphql/queries"
import {createAuth} from "../../../../src/graphql/mutations"

export default async function callback(req, res) {
      const record = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getAuth, {emailId: "abc@gmail.com"}))
      res.status(200).json({ record });
}
```

**aws-exports.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://dummyUrl.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "da2-************"
};

export default awsmobile;
```

**_app.js**

```js
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import config from "../aws-exports"
Amplify.configure(config)

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
 // App logic

})
```

**GraphQL Schema**

```js
type Auth @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }])  {
  emailId: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String
  screen_name: String
  profile_img: String
  userSession: String
  tokenType: String
  accessToken: String
  accessSecret: String
  refreshToken: String
  accessScope: String
}
```

**Package.json**

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@emoji-mart/data": "^1.0.6",
    "@emoji-mart/react": "^1.0.1",
    "aes256": "^1.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.37",
    "emoji-mart": "^5.2.2",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
```

Amplify.yml

```js
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**
I've found how the server side process work with amplify and graphql. Please refer to [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js/). On the server side, you need to pass the API KEY explicitly into the graphql request as that page writes.

==========
I'm using appsync, but appsync pure directives. So just let me provide the reference below. Please confirm the rule follows [this way](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/).

{ allow: public, provider: apiKey }

Comment: Thank you for your response. apiKey is the default provider but I've tried that by explicitly adding the provider apiKey and it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks to your try. Where did you deploy? EC2?

Comment: AWS Lambda via Amplify.

Comment: So the problem should be in lambda. Lambda role is correct?

Comment: Lambda is able to make the call. That's how I'm sending the error details to the browser. Plus lambda roles are auto configured by Amplify when you deploy the resources. I think something else is missing. Just not sure what it is.